Asymptotic Normality of Reduced Rank Regression
I am trying to follow the Multivariate Reduced Rank Regression textbook by Reinsel, Velu, and Chen. I start with a reduced rank regression
$$
Y_t = C X_t + \epsilon_t \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad Y_t = A B X_{t} + \epsilon_t
$$
and I am interested in the asymptotic covariance of $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times r}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times N}$.
I know that based on the perturbation expansion of matrices, the eigenvectors of $M = \Sigma_{\epsilon \epsilon}^{-1/2} \widehat{\Sigma}_{yx} \widehat{\Sigma}_{xx}^{-1} \widehat{\Sigma}_{xy} \Sigma_{\epsilon \epsilon}^{-1/2}$ can be expanded around the eigenvectors $V_j$ of $N = \Sigma_{\epsilon \epsilon}^{-1/2} \Sigma_{yx} \Sigma_{xx}^{-1} \Sigma_{xy} \Sigma_{\epsilon \epsilon}^{-1/2}$ to obtain
$$
\widehat{V}_j \sim V_j + \sum_{\substack{i \neq j}}^{m} \frac{1}{(\lambda_j^2 - \lambda_i^2)} V_i \left[V_j'(M - N)V_i\right] \quad (j = 1, \ldots, r).
$$
where $\lambda^2$ are the eigenvalues associated with the eigenvectors. I then can obtain
$$
\widehat{\Sigma}_{yx} \widehat{\Sigma}_{xx}^{-1} \widehat{\Sigma}_{xy} - \Sigma_{yx} \Sigma_{xx}^{-1} \Sigma_{xy} = C U_T + U_T' C' + U_T' \widehat{\Sigma}_{xx}^{-1} U_T + C (\widehat{\Sigma}_{xx} - \Sigma_{xx}) C',
$$
where $U_T = T^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^T X_k \epsilon_k$ and I drop the last two terms because I assume the predictors are non-stochastic. I can then use $\Sigma_{\epsilon \epsilon}^{-1/2}C = \Sigma_{\epsilon \epsilon} A B = V B$ to obtain
$$
\widehat{V}_j \sim V_j + \sum_{\substack{i \neq j}}^{m} \frac{1}{(\lambda_j^2 - \lambda_i^2)} V_i \left[\underbrace{V_j' V B U_T \Sigma_{\epsilon \epsilon}^{-1/2} V_i}_{(a)} + \underbrace{V_j' \Sigma_{\epsilon \epsilon}^{-1/2} U_T' B' V' V_i}_{(b)} \right] \quad (j = 1, \ldots, r).
$$
Then using kronecker product rules, I can vectorize $(a)$ to be
$$
(V_i' \Sigma_{\epsilon \epsilon}^{-1/2} \otimes V_j' V B) \text{vec}(U_T),
$$
and $(b)$ to be
$$
(V_i' V B \otimes V_j' \Sigma_{\epsilon \epsilon}^{-1/2}) \text{vec}(U_T').
$$
However, I do not know how to remove the transpose from the $(b)$ term to factor out the $\text{vec}(U_T)$. One idea I had was to use the commutation matrix $K_{mn} \text{vec} (U_T') = \text{vec}(U_T)$, but this did not explain the last big $O_p$ part. The final result should be
$$
T^{1/2} (\widehat{V}_j - V_j) = 
$$
$$
T^{1/2} \sum_{\substack{i \neq j}}^{m} \frac{1}{(\lambda_j^2 - \lambda_i^2)} V_i \left[(V_i' \Sigma_{\epsilon \epsilon}^{-1/2} \otimes V_j' V B) + (V_j' \Sigma_{\epsilon \epsilon}^{-1/2} \otimes V_i' V B)\right] \operatorname{vec}(U_T) + O_p(T^{-1/2}).
$$
Moreover, I am unsure how the scaling $T^{1/2}$ comes in. Is this from the $M-N$? Thank you in advance!

Ah I remember now, the last $O_p (T^{-1/2})$ term comes from dropping the third last term in $M-N$ where $U_T' \Sigma_{xx}^{-1} U_T$ is (1/T) but multiplying by T^{-1/2} results in something that is $O_p (T^{-1/2})$.
